# Two ways to generate the same $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

So I am reading this lecture containing the following proof that $\cal A_1 = \cal A_2$ when:

- $\cal A_1$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C_1 = \{ (-\infty, a ] ,  a \in \cal Q \} $
- $\cal A_2$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C_2 = \{ (a,b), a,b \in \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\} \} $

This is the part of the proof showing that $\cal A_1 \subset \cal A_2$:

> Let's consider $ (-\infty, a ] \in C_1 $. Then its complement $ (a,
>  +\infty ) \in \cal A_1 $. It is also clear that $ (a, +\infty ) \in \cal A_2 $. $ \cal A_2 $ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the elements
>   of $C_1$, therefore $\cal A_1 \subset \cal A_2$.

I don't understand this proof. We have not showed that any element $ (-\infty, a ] \in C_1 $ is also in $\cal A_2$, have we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof shows that for $M \in C_1$, we have $M^c \in \mathcal{A}_2$. Since $\mathcal{A}_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it follows that $M = (M^c)^c \in \mathcal{A}_2$, so $C_1 \subset \mathcal{A}_2$, and therefore $\mathcal{A}_1 \subset \mathcal{A}_2$.